# Unable to figure out some vimrc settings

Tags: vim

I came across the following lines in a vimrc file and can't figure out what they're supposed to do or how they're supposed to work. Am thrown off by the use of the $ sign. Does it have any special meaning or is it used in a regular manner like any other character?

```
" Parenthesis/bracket expanding
vnoremap $1 <esc>`>a)<esc>`<i(<esc>
vnoremap $2 <esc>`>a]<esc>`<i[<esc>
vnoremap $3 <esc>`>a}<esc>`<i{<esc>
vnoremap $$ <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>
vnoremap $q <esc>`>a'<esc>`<i'<esc>
vnoremap $e <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>

" Map auto complete of (, ", ', [
inoremap $1 ()<esc>i
inoremap $2 []<esc>i
inoremap $3 {}<esc>i
inoremap $4 {<esc>o}<esc>O
inoremap $q ''<esc>i
inoremap $e ""<esc>i
inoremap $t <><esc>i
```

If anyone's interested. [This](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html) is the link to the vimrc

Comment: `:h mapmodes` may be helpful.

Comment: Andrew, I'm familiar with the way mappings work. I'm not sure what the $ sign means here. I didn't find the answer in mapmode. Is there some particular sub-section I should be looking out for?

Comment: The `$` is not particularly special, it's just the first key (of two) in the sequence of the left-hand-side of the mapping. See my answer for a fuller explanation.

Comment: I recommend Tim Pope's excellent [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) to handle most of these mappings

Comment: @Michael I'm using surround.vim. Just stumbled upon this vimrc and was going through it to see if I could learn something new; I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at just two of these.

The first is a [visual-mode mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:vnoremap):

```
" Parenthesis/bracket expanding
vnoremap $1 <esc>`>a)<esc>`<i(<esc>
```

This wraps the selection in `()` when you type <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>. First it jumps to the end of the selection ([`'>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%60%3E)) and [`a`ppend](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#a)s a `)` before jumping to the beginning of the selection ([`'<`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%3E)) and [`i`nsert](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i)ing a `(`.

This is an [insert-mode mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-i):

```
" Map auto complete of (, ", ', [
inoremap $1 ()<esc>i
```

This inserts `()` when you type <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and leaves the cursor in between the two parentheses.